# How do I call this stored procedure from .net?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I try to get number of rows from database which the number of column receiver for exp is x.

Stored procedure definition:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[lattercountin] 
    (@receiver NVarchar(150)) 
as 
begin 
    select count(idlatter) as cnt 
    from sendlatter 
    where receiver = @receiver 
end
```

This the C# code:

```
string prc = "lattercountin";

SqlCommand cmd = Phone_Book.getEntries(prc);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@receiver", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

try
{
    cmd.Parameters["@receiver"].Value = Entry.receiver;

    SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    data.Fill(dt);

    Entry.sender = (string)dt.Rows[0][0];
}
finally
{
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection.Close();
}
```

and this is error :

** OP where is your error **

Comment: That does not look like an error, are you sure that's correct? Also you probably need to include the code for getEnries too.

Comment: Looks like you need to set the command type to StoredProcedure.

Comment: @SeanLange And use `ExecuteScalar`. There is absolutely no need to create a `DataTable` to fetch one value.